# How do I get the location that was touched?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0, google-maps-mobile

I have made a sample Android application that displays a Google map using phonegap. I want to get the location of the place that was touched on the map. Is there any method for that?

Answer (score 0):

Its solution for Android MapView, but I'm sure that you have similar method in PhoneGap.
I think you need to extend Overlay class and override OnTap method.

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p,MapView mapView){
Log.d("TOUCHED_PLACE", "Latitutde:"+p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + " Longitude:"+p.getLongitude()/1E6);

}
```

More info:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay#onTap%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView%29

:)